# how to update all rows in a column sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want update all rows in a column(A) but the column should fill with column(B) and column(c) and I should say it's should for all rows

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Col_B | Col_C | Col_A |
+-------+-------+-------+
| x     | y     | xy    |        
| s     | u     | su    |         
| h     | z     | hz    |        
| t     | t     | tt    |          
| m     | m     | mm    |
```

Comment: what have you tried ? can you post your current query ?

Comment: update [TableName] set Col_A=Col_B+Col_C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `UPDATE` statement will do what you want:

`UPDATE [mytable] SET [Col_A] = CONCAT([Col_B], [Col_C])`

Note the lack of `WHERE` clause will cause it to be applied to all rows in the table.

Comment: thanks buddy .                       
my problem fixed

Answer (score 1):

Just Try a Simple Update

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET Col_A = Col_B+Col_C
```